# EF4 DbContext: How to centrally audit database reads

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, audit

I know, I know. Why would anyone want to do that? The application already audits changes to data but now the business wants to audit all reads as well (without a convincing user story, I have to say). I have given them all the arguments against, but they insist.

So does EF/DbContext provide an extension point that would be suitable for intercepting all records returned from the database and writing an entry in an audit trail? Or is there another sensible way of doing this?

Comment: I would seriously want a decent justification for this. Else slap on the SQL Profiler, watch the DB grind to a halt and be done with it.

Comment: I agree, I agree. But business thinks it knows best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized.aspx).  MSDN snippet:

> Occurs when a new entity object is created from data in the data
> source as part of a query or load operation.
>
> This event is raised after all scalar, complex, and reference
> properties have been set on an object, but before collections are
> loaded. If an object with the same key value exists in the object
> context, the Entity Framework will **not recreate the object and this
> event will not be raised**.

But this would only track items read from Db through your EF implementation.

Comment: But this wont track field access (and subsequent reading of records already in memory).

Comment: It has some limitations, but at least this approach gives me a way of centralising the code so won't require too much work to implement and will be easy to remove when they realise I wasn't joking when I said it would mean a serious performance penalty :)

Comment: Your performance penalty can be reduced by not performing the audit synchronously but putting the changes in a Queue and processing the queue from another process.  Then the only penalty is the writing to the queue and perhaps the serialization of the objects

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt Nice idea, though perhaps expensive from a development and maintenance point of view, given that we are not currently using queuing technology.

Comment: Then you could just create a `BackgroundWorker` to do it asynchronously.  No queue and your queries are not impacted by the audit.